# Polarization of longitudinal modes of He-Ne laser

Tags: laser, polarization

I read  (in the book *Gas lasers* and at the site https://www.experimental-engineering.co.uk/helium-neon-lasers/theory-modes-coherence/) that for red (633 nm) He-Ne lasers at least, adjacent longitudinal modes tend to be orthogonally polarized  and  also adjacent modes in a so-called “random polarized” red (632.8 nm) He-Ne laser are almost always orthogonally polarized, with the polarization axes fixed relative to the tube. So, what is the physics explanation behind these facts, or are there any literature where this is explained in detail?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a HeNe laser will use a tube using Brewster Angled windows.  Such windows are tilted relative to the optical axis of the laser and has the function of reducing the loss of one specific state of polarization (linear polarized, P-polarized).

If the laser doesn't have such a polarizing selection element, then polarization hole burning by one particular longitudinal mode will leave higher gain for the orthogonal state of polarization for the adjacent longitudinal mode.